# How to rescue or prevent rails database connection exception and allow controller action to continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, controller

I am trying to catch database connection issues on a specific request and take a different action when the database is down.

for example:

*config/routes.rb*

```
get 'my_route' => 'my_controller#my_action'
```

*app/controllers/my_controller.rb*

```
class MyController < Public::ApplicationController
  def my_action
    begin
      url = database_lookup
    rescue Mysql2::Error => e
      url = fallback_lookup
    end
    redirect_to url
  end

  def database_lookup
    # get info from db
  end

  def fallback_lookup
    # lookup info in redis cache instead
  end
end
```

This might work in certain situations, however if the database goes down and a new request comes in, active record middleware raises an exception long before ever reaching the controller.

I have been messing with Middleware to try and catch the error and do something else, but its not looking too promising.

What i'm trying is:
*application.rb*

```
config.middleware.insert_after 'ActionDispatch::RemoteIp', 'DatabaseExceptionHandler'
```

*app/middleware/database_exception_handler.rb*

```
class DatabaseExceptionHandler
  def initialize app
    @app = app
  end

  def call env
    @status, @headers, @response = @app.call(env)
    [@status, @headers, @response]
  rescue Mysql2::Error => e
    [@status, @headers, @response]
  end
end
```

This is allowing me to catch connection exceptions that are raised when the request runs, but it doesn't help me much. I need to somehow get to a controller action still.

I think a simpler approach would be to skip all the active record connection nonsense for a specific controller action.

It seems silly to force a database connection for something that might not even need the database.

Anyone have any better ideas than what i've come up with so far?

Comment: What's the stack trace for the error you see in middleware?

Answer (score 0):

> I think a simpler approach would be to skip all the active record
>   connection nonsense for a specific controller action.

No doable or even a good idea. Rails does not process the configuration and middleware on a per request basis and that would not work with any kind of server that speeds the process up by booting up rails in the background.

> This is allowing me to catch connection exceptions that are raised
>   when the request runs, but it doesn't help me much. I need to somehow
>   get to a controller action still.

This is probably a fools errand. If Rails bailed in the initialization process the integrity of the system is probably not great and you can't just continue on like its business as usual.

What you can do is set `config.exceptions_app` to [customize the error pages](https://anoobbava.github.io/blog/2018/03/22/create-custom-error-pages-in-rails/). And get a less flaky database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your assumption that I have a flaky database is ill conceived. It has run fine for years. I am instead hoping to prevent any downtime with an upcoming migration that will require the database to be down for a few hours. The databases is 60GB now and downtime cannot be avoided in this situation. This particular endpoint gets millions of visitors per month, so trying to solve this issue is a big deal to me. It might take some creativity, but anything is possible :)